# What is the exact meaning of the word additional?

Tags: word-meaning, vocabulary, definition

I would like to ask one question regarding the meaning of the word **additional**.

Does the word additional carry on the connotation of optional?

Like for example if I write "additional settings" in a manual, does that implies those settings can be skipped?

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't carry any such connotations. It means simply "ones that haven't been mentioned/discussed yet."

Comment: Exactly! My boss thinks it does.... (sigh)